# Determine whether the system $A\mathbb x=\mathbb b$ is consistent by examing how $\mathbb b$ relates to the column vectors of $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> **10.** For each of the choices of $A$ and $\mathbb b$ that follow, determine whether the system $A\mathbb x=\mathbb b$ is consistent by examing how $\mathbb b$ relates to the column vectors of $A$. Explain your answers in each case.
>
> (a) $$A=\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\-2&-1\end{bmatrix}\qquad\mathbb b=\begin{bmatrix}3\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
>
> (b) $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&4\\2&3\end{bmatrix}\qquad\mathbb b=\begin{bmatrix}5\\5\end{bmatrix}$$
>
> (c) $$A=\begin{bmatrix}3&2&1\\3&2&1\\3&2&1\end{bmatrix}\qquad\mathbb b=\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{bmatrix}$$

I do not understand this. How can I solve these?

Comment: You should show first what you've tried. And then we can help you

Answer (score 3):

For example: in question a), the equation $Ax = b$ becomes
$$
2x_1 + x_2 = 3\\
-2x_1 - x_2 = 1
$$
Note, however, that the second row of $A$ is a multiple of the first row of $A$.  In particular,
$$
(-1)[2x_1 + x_2] = (-1)[3] \implies\\
-2x_1 - x_2 = -3
$$
So, our system equations tells us that $-2x_1 - x_2 = 1$ *and* that $-2x_1 - x_2 = -3$.  However, it is impossible for $-2x_1 - x_2$ to equal $1$ *and* $-3$.  We therefore conclude that the system of equations is **inconsistent**.

The other questions can be answered similarly.

Comment: thanks. i got (a) and (b) . but what about (c) ?? will u kindly make it clear?

Comment: @sovon (c) is even easier; there's no multiplying to do.  Set up the system of equations and you should immediately find a contradiction.